How to add transitions/animations on elements changed by htmx via websockets?
I'm using htmx, websockets and tailwind, I believe this should "just" work, but I have the following element:
<div hx-ext="ws" ws-connect="/ws/generate/">
  <div id="to-animate" class="transition-all w-0"></div>
</div>

but when I swap it out through a websocket, the element get's replaced but no animation is happening.
I tried adding morphdom incase htmx is unable to match the right elements, but without any success.
How can I animate elements swapped out through websockets in HTMX?
